# How to download Keras_contrib (and other packages that is not avaliable in conda) to Pycharm?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, anaconda

I am quite familiar with Pycharm except 1 thing that I can't seem to figure out how to download Keras_contrib which is not availble in conda's channel and conda-forge channel which is also often used.

I have read the following article which suggest to add additional channel to conda.

"How to Install a Package in PyCharm when project interpreter is set to conda, and the package is not provided/listed by conda? 1"

but as I mentioned Keras_contrib is not provided, and I am not sure quite sure how to download it.

I managed to install Keras_contrib sucessfully to my environment which is also used by Pycharm interpreter, but for some reason, Pycharm does not recognize it.

I follow instruction given in https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib

which is running setup.py install

Here are the questions

1. By doing this Does it get install in the site_packages automatically? because I do not see it.

if I have to do it manually, how come my environment can recognize it, but Pycharm cannot.

2. Is there a default location in which environment and Pycharm usually look at?

because it would make sense in this case that one may recognize it while other may not.

3. How can I download Keras_contrib which is not avaliable in well known channel?
4. Is there other way to check that Pycharm Interpreter is compatible with my anaconda environment other than looking folder it is linked to?

In my case they link to the same environment, but Pycharm just cannot recognize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

so Pycharm looks at site-packages of your environment.

I solved by problem that Pycharm cannot recognize the packages while anacoda env can by copy and past the Keras_contrib to the site-packages. (I still find this to be strange if any one answer to this. Feel free to comment)